# LNK1104 cannot open file 'legacy_stdio_definitions.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I've ported my project from vs 2012 to vs 2015.

The Library i'm consuming is also built from vs 2015.

I build my project using makefile and getting this error

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'legacy_stdio_definitions.lib'
```

if i build the same in vs 2012 , it works fine.

What this error is all about?

Comment: Unusual problem to have.  Start by looking in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib directory for that file.  Next make sure that the makefile sets the LIB environment variable correctly.  Next consider that you should not need this library at all, it is a hack to help port code that did not use #include correctly, so remove it from the link dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the project in Visual Studio, then click Project at the top menu bar. Click "Properties", "Linker", and then "Input". In "Additional Dependencies", click the down arrow beside and click "Edit". Add "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" and click "OK", then "OK".

Comment: I'm using make file to build, so these options are not available to me.