# Compile project in visual studio with OpenSSL as a static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openssl, static-libraries

My Visual Studio project works when OpenSSL is loaded dynamically but breaks when I use OpenSSL as a static library.

The error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _sscanf referenced in
>   function _OPENSSL_cpuid_setup libcrypto32MTd.lib(cryptlib.obj)

Comment: [legacy_stdio_definitions.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32418900/4074081) may help if you are using VS 2015 and above and OpenSSL library is precompiled by older version.

Comment: its work but now there are another 12 errors like that:

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___iob_func referenced in function _openssl_load_privkey

Comment: This one looks [almost impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34655235/4074081) to fix correctly. So, you'd better recompile OpenSSL or download binary precompiled with your version of Visual Studio.